# Android from Pixels mockup to dp measure

Tags: android

Hi I am working on an Android project and I have the following information from the graphical designer:
[image]

The design is done for an Android hdpi screen which should be 960 x 540 px (640 x 360 dp) / hdpi / Normal screen based on Android SDK documentation. 
Inside Android studio I am trying to replicate the layout but I seriously struggle to calculate the DP starting from this mock. Is there any good tutorial I should follow?
I tried on a Nexus 5 but as soon as I switch to Nexus 6 for example the layout is completely different and I am using dp all over in my XML.